# составные пути в react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Почему при попытке обратиться по составному пути компонент не отрисовывается?

```
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path={"/user/info"} component={UserInfoComponent}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: `path="/user/info"`?

Comment: это не помогло да и не понятно почему должно было помочь

Comment: Версия react'a какая?

Comment: версия реакта 16.8.2

Comment: Как Вы импортируете `Router`? React native или обычный?

Comment: `import {Route, Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: Попробуйте так: `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"`, а путь оставить `path="/user/info"`

Comment: Не помогло. Возможно сборка вебпаком на это как то повлияла? 'GET http://localhost:8081/user/index-bundle.js 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: `historyApiFallback: true` в конфиге webpack'a есть? Для пути "/' `exact` написан?

Comment: да, есть и да, написан

Comment: суть в том, что при обращении, допустим, по адресу "/user" все работает корректно

Comment: Попробуйте: `path="/user/:info"`

Comment: все равно не получается)

Comment: Можете залить компонент на codepen?

Comment: Если честно, мне кажется что проблема кроется в вебпаке. Или я неправильно понял, или он пытается найти бандл в той директории, где его нет

Comment: Скорее всего так и есть :)

Comment: и что с этим можно сделать?) потому что положить бандл в директорию /dist/user мне, разумеется, не дают

Comment: Нужно смотреть что у Вас в конфиге находится :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Pa9cqw0q

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в составном роуте. Посмотрите [документацию](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) и проверьте, правильно ли вы импорторуете необходимые компоненты. Чаще всего это `{ BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect }`.